# Numba error when attempting to instantiate NumPy RandomState

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I have a class that I'd like to speed up with Numba. The class employs a "random number generator" for each instance by simply creating an instance of NumPy's RandomState with a particular seed (thus I can replicate my work later). When I use Numba's autojit, I get a strange error which doesn't arise in "regular" Python.

Fortunately this behavior is extremely simple to replicate. Here's a simple example which illustrates the error:

```
from numpy.random import RandomState
from numba import autojit

# ------- This works in "regular Python" ------------

class SillyClass1(object):
    def __init__(self, seed):
        self.RNG = RandomState(seed)
    def draw_uniform(self):
        return self.RNG.uniform(0,1)

test1 = SillyClass1(123456)

test1.draw_uniform()

# Output:
# 0.12696983303810094


# The following code -- exactly the same as above, but with the @autojit 
# decorator, doesn't work, and throws an error which I am having a hard  
# time understanding how to fix:

@autojit
class SillyClass2(object):
    def __init__(self, seed):
        self.RNG = RandomState(seed)
    def draw_uniform(self):
        return self.RNG.uniform(0,1)

test2 = SillyClass2(123456)

test2.draw_uniform()

# Output:
#
# ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
# <ipython-input-86-a18f95c11a1b> in <module>()
#      10 
#      11 
# ---> 12 test2 = SillyClass2(123456)
#      13 
#      14 test2.draw_uniform()
# 
# ...
# 
# ValueError: object of too small depth for desired array
```

I'm using the Anaconda distributionon Ubuntu 13.10.

Any thoughts?

*Edit*: I found a work-around, which is to simply use Python's standard "random.Random" instead of NumPys' "numpy.random.RandomState"

Example:

```
from random import Random 
@autojit
class SillyClass3(object):
    def __init__(self, seed):
        self.RNG = Random(seed)
    def draw_uniform(self):
        return self.RNG.uniform(0,1)

test3 = SillyClass3(123456)

test3.draw_uniform()

# Output:
# 0.8056271362589
```

This works for my immediate application (although other problems arose immediately, hurray).

However, this fix will not work for future algorithms for which I know I will need to use numpy.random.RandomState. So my question still stands -- does anyone have any insight regarding the original error, and/or workarounds for using numy.random.RandomState in Numba?

Answer (score 1):

A late answer, but the issue is that Numba [does not support](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/numpysupported.html#random) Numpy's `RandomState` object (as of July, 2019). Neither does it support setting random states using the [Python standard library](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html#pysupported-random).

However, given that `np.random.seed` is supported by Numba, you can use a numpy's PRNG within a jitted function by passing a `seed` parameter into the function and then calling the `np.random.seed(seed)` method therein. From the [Numba documentation](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.43.0/reference/numpysupported.html):

> Numba supports top-level functions from the numpy.random module, but
> does not allow you to create individual RandomState instances. The
> same algorithms are used as for the standard random module (and
> therefore the same notes apply), but with an independent internal
> state: seeding or drawing numbers from one generator won’t affect the
> other.

#### Code Example

```
import random, numba, numpy

@numba.njit
def random_func(seed: int = 1234) -> str:
    seeded_prng = numpy.random.seed(seed)
    # Do random stuff
    random_computation = numpy.random.uniform(0, 1)
    return random_computation

# Example Invocation
seed = 1337
random_result = random_func(seed)
print(random_result)
```

Which should yield:

```
0.2620246750155817
```

If you'd like to have a different random state for each class instance, you'll need to have a separate thread for each class because the PRNGs are tied to the thread they are instantiated in. Fortunately, Numba handles this automatically provided each class occurs in its own thread:

> Since version 0.28.0, the generator is thread-safe and fork-safe. Each
> thread and each process will produce independent streams of random
> numbers.

Finally, if you are targeting CUDA, there are a number of methods that allow you to work directly with a GPU enabled PRNG that could be handy. See this page from the [Numba documentation](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/cuda/random.html).